# How to parse(and create rows) dataframe for an elements?

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please say, which is the best way to parse rows?

Data have:

```
import pandas as pd
data_have = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["aa.bb.cc.d","a.b.cc.d.e.ff"],
                          "id1": ["001","002"],
                          "id2": ["aaa","bbb"]})
print(data_have)
```

Data want:

```
data_want = pd.DataFrame({"name": "aa.bb.cc.d", "aa.bb.cc.d", "a.b.cc.d.e.ff", "a.b.cc.d.e.ff", "a.b.cc.d.e.ff"],
                          "id1": ["001","001","002","002","002"],
                          "id2": ["aaa","aaa","bbb","bbb","bbb"],
                          "First":["aa", "cc","a","cc","e"],
                          "Second":["bb","d","b","d","ff"]})
print(data_want)
```

What I want to do is:

1. create 2 additional columns (“First”, “Second”)
2. sequentially take a pair of elements and put them in these columns (the odd element will always be the first, the even element will always be the second)
3. for each pair, if there is a need create a row and duplicate the existing values of the "name" column into it (table "have" consists of 2 lines, table "want consists of 5 lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your dataframe, splitting your names and then creating new rows for each couple of odd and even positions.

```
data_want = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'First', 'Second'])
count = 0
# Iterate through our data_have splitting each name
for d in data_have['name'].apply(lambda x : x.split('.') ):
    # Iterate through the splitted values
    for i in range(len(d)):
        # Set Second
        if i % 2:
            second = d[i] 
            # Insert the row
            data_want.loc[count] = [d, first, second]
            count+=1

        # Set First
        else:
            first = d[i]
```

And your output is:

```
    name                  First Second
0   [aa, bb, cc, d]         aa  bb
1   [aa, bb, cc, d]         cc  d
2   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    a   b
3   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    cc  d
4   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    e   ff
```

> Edit

Adding the ids columns and applying a bit of optimization:

```
# Create wanted dataframe.
data_want = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'First', 'Second', 'id1', 'id2'])
count = 0

# Create a column with the name column already spplited.
data_have.loc[:, 'list_splitted'] = data_have['name'].str.split('.')

# Iterate through the dataframe inserting new rows.
for index, row in data_have.iterrows():
    d = row['list_splitted']

    for i in range(len(d)):
        # Set Second
        if i % 2:
            second = d[i] 
            # Insert the row
            data_want.loc[count] = [d, first, second, row['id1'], row['id2']]
            count+=1

        # Set First
        else:
            first = d[i]
```

The output:

```
        name                First   Second  id1 id2
0   [aa, bb, cc, d]         aa       bb     001 aaa
1   [aa, bb, cc, d]         cc       d      001 aaa
2   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    a        b      002 bbb
3   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    cc       d      002 bbb
4   [a, b, cc, d, e, ff]    e        ff     002 bbb
```

Comment: Thank you very much man. The idea of using table cells as an elements is very cool! I didn't thought is it allowed here in Python.

Comment: I've added 2 columns with id's in data_have. Maybe I will do it myself during the day, but if not.. could you please modify your code to get id's to the output table as well?

Comment: I was looking at "df.iat", you did smarter. Thank you! :)